# In jqplot graph, jqplotSaveImage() is not working

Tags: jquery, exception, graph, jqplot

I am using jqplot graph, in that i am trying to save the graph as image by using jqplotSaveImage(), but when i triggered this function i get the following exception,

Unhandled exception at line 3, column 146939 in jquery.jqplot.min.js

0x8007007a - JavaScript runtime error: unknown exception

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override this function:

```
$.fn.jqplotSaveImage = function() {
    var imgData = $(this).jqplotToImageStr({});
    if (imgData) {
        window.location.href = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    }

};
```

Comment: @Nandha Kumar could yo please vote up for this answer if it's really helped you